# Bash-like partial tab-complete for filenames in Vim

Tags: command-line, autocompletion

In Bash, when there are several files with the same prefix and I type part of the prefix and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it completes the common prefix and allows me to continue typing to differentiate among the possible results.

In Vim, when there are several files with the same prefix and I type part of the prefix and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it completes the entire first match and lets me then select among all the matches. To reduce the set, I have to backspace until I get to the end of the common part, then type some more and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> again.

I often have *lots* of files where there is a long common prefix, and the file I want is not among the first (for example, a directory of project files containing, among other things, various makefiles all with the name `Makefile.{whatever}`).

Can I make Vim complete more like Bash to save lots of key strokes?

Bonus if this can apply to other completions as well (for example, enum values that all have the same prefix)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the `wildmode` option to control this.

If you use `:set wildmode=list:longest`, you get behaviour similar to bash.

I personally prefer to use `:set wildmode=list:longest,full`; this will list completions, but on the *second* <kbd>Tab</kbd> press, you can cycle between the entries (and <kbd>Shift+Tab</kbd> to cycle in the reverse).

This applies to *all* completions done by Vim.

See: [`:help 'wildmode'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27wildmode%27)

Comment: Not insert mode completions! You need `completeopt` for that.

Comment: Thanks! wildmode and completeopt are exactly what I was looking for!